# Background Location services for android

Tags: android, location

I have an android app that I am developing and I need to have a Service running that checks the user's location at a defined interval.

I've found other posts and Google's documentation, but I found them all very confusing, where people are saying different things.

If someone could please help me on this, I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do create repetitive alarm using alarm manager.

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html